# when enter a date in text box start date automatically Show dates of next one year in other textbox endtextbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, date

I have two textboxes in my asp.net using c# code

HTML Code

```
       <tr>
      <td></td>
   <td style="text-align: right"><asp:TextBox ID="TxtEndDate" runat="server"    
    Width="177px" AutoPostBack="True" style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox>   
      </td>
  <td style="text-align: right">end date</td>
 <td style="text-align: right">
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextStartDate" runat="server" Width="177px"  
 AutoPostBack="True"  style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox></td>
   <td style="text-align: right; direction: rtl;">
   start date
 </td>
 </tr>
```

I want that when I enter date in dd/mm/yyyy in first text box (TxtStartDate), it will automatically fill the second text box (TxtEndDate) by adding plus one year in above entered date.

I tried This JavaScript but it is not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$('#TextStartDate').blur(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
var regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
if (regex.test(value)) {
    var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(reformat(value)));
    var year = myDate.getYear() + 1;
    var month = myDate.getYear() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    var day = myDate.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    $('#TxtEndDate').val(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
   } else {
    alert('invalid date');
    // this will prevent from leaving the input until the date is correct
    $(this).focus();
   }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your id's. ASP.NET hijacks your ids and prepends stuff on them. Change all your jquery id calls to

```
$("[id*=TxtStartDate]")
$("[id*=TxtEndDate]")
```

So, in your original script, do this:

```
<script>
$('[id*=TextStartDate]').blur(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
var regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
if (regex.test(value)) {
    var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(reformat(value)));
    var year = myDate.getYear() + 1;
    var month = myDate.getYear() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    var day = myDate.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    $('[id*=TxtEndDate]').val(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
   } else {
    alert('invalid date');
    // this will prevent from leaving the input until the date is correct
    $(this).focus();
   }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean can you explain it please

Comment: Here, let's move this to a chat to prevent too many back and forths. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74965/when-enter-a-date-in-text-box-start-date-automatically-show-dates-of-next-one-yea

Comment: It is not allowed I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk in chat

Comment: Okay. You'll have to debug this a bit more to see if your jquery events are even firing. Comment out all your script stuff and send an alert for the .blur function. Let me know if you get that.

Comment: Change your .blur function to this and let me know if you get the alert.
    <script>
    $('[id*=TextStartDate]').blur(function () {
         alert('test');
    });
    </script>

Comment: Nothing happen I changed but nothing happen

Comment: It's clear you need more debugging and I don't want to keep filling up this with back and forths. Feel free to email me and I can help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a more simple function:

    `var dateParts=value.split('/');
    $('#TxtEndDate').val(dateParts[0]+'/'+dateParts[1]+'/'+(parseInt(dateParts[2])+1));`

To access server controls with javascript you need to do this `$('#<%=TextStartDate.ClientId%>')` because asp.net controls IDs are generated at runtime.
Also set AutoPostBack to false or else the page will be refreshed every time one of the TextBox lost focus

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean can you explain it please

Comment: When an asp control is converted to HTML the id of the element is generated at runtime.  For example `<asp:TextBox ID="TextStartDate" runat="server" Width="177px"  
 AutoPostBack="True"  style="height: 22px"></asp:TextBox>` will be rendered as `<input id="Form1_TextStartDate" ></input>` so the id is different from the one you used

Comment: where I should put $('#<%=TextStartDate.ClientId%>') ??

Comment: That is synonyms with my example. Replace your jquery calls like showed in my example.

Comment: @fischgeek I changed it but still not working I don't know what is the problem and no errors

Comment: Try setting `AutoPostBack` to false on `TextStartDate`